# Using multiple measurements to create a view in Grafana with InfluxDB

Tags: grafana, influxdb

In my Influx I have two (2) measurements called: *jenkins_data* and *jenkins_custom_data*. I want to create a view that uses fields from both measurements. Something like this:

```
SELECT count("build_successful") FROM "jenkins_data" WHERE "jenkins_custom_data.branch"='master' AND "build_result"='SUCCESSFUL'
```

Note that *build_successful* is a field in *jenkins_data* and *build_result* is a tag in *jenkins_data* while *branch* is a field of *jenkins_custom_data*

Is it possible to do such combination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is achieved with **SQL Joins** but currently InfluxDB does not support this (see [this issue](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/3552) where it is discussed extensively).

According to [this comment](https://community.influxdata.com/t/how-can-i-combine-two-different-measurements/6936/4) by [Anaisdg](https://community.influxdata.com/u/Anaisdg) (influx staff) this will not be possible with InfluxQL, but will be possible in the future with the planned query language [Flux](https://www.influxdata.com/blog/announcing-ifql-a-new-query-language-and-engine-for-influxdb/)